# How to make python strings inside lists into splitted strings

Tags: python

If i have a list like: `['wordone','word2','worD']`
how can i make it look like: `[['w','o','r','d','o','n','e'],['w','o','r','d','2'],['w','o','r','D']]`

Comment: What have you tried? Please include your code in your question.

Comment: I ve been thinking for 30 mins for a loop, yet i couldnt come up with any successful loop, (that s why i posted the questio on here..)

Comment: Divide and conquer the problem. First try to turn `wordone` into `['w','o','r','d','o','n','e']`*, then re-run that code multiple times with different inputs

Comment: @byxor vice versa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One could do it this way:

```
lst = ['wordone','word2','worD']

new_lst = [[letter for letter in word] for word in lst]

print(new_lst)
# output: [['w', 'o', 'r', 'd', 'o', 'n', 'e'], ['w', 'o', 'r', 'd', '2'], ['w', 'o', 'r', 'D']]
```

Comment: or just `list(map(list, lst))`

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `map` function, I'll have to look into it...

Answer (score 1):

Almost similar to the above but I find this one slightly more readable

```py
words = ['wordone','word2','worD']
new_list = [list(word) for word in words]
print(new_list)
```